# Multimedia Project

Tags: creative-writing

I wish to assign a multimedia project to a creative writing class of which I am a tutor, but I am running dry on ideas. Songs, narratives and dances have become commonplace. Any suggestions for something new for students on the undergraduate level that would both stimulate their creativity and help fulfil the criteria of a multimedia project? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does creative writing mean in the context of a multimedia project? I'd guess your pupils don't actually dance or sing, but rather write the text for a song or the choreography of a dance. Otherwise it wouldn't be *writing*, would it? Could you explain a bit what your students are actually supposed to do? I've never been part of such a course.

Comment: Hahaha they do dance and sing! They craft the lyrics themselves. The one danced in new-motion to words said in rhythms! They have to incorporate one other element of media along with their writing and present it.

Comment: Do they have to present the text on a stage (i.e. speak it), or can they show movies or present printed or painted works (like posters)? In the middle ages people used to sing stories accompanied by pictures. See the illustrations here: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A4nkelsang

Comment: Welcome to Writers! Questions on Stack Exchange sites need to be a bit more focused than this, I'm afraid. Please have a look at our [help center](http://writers.stackexchange.com/help/) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your examples, I guess that the question is:

What forms of multimedia could students use to tell a story?

They could create:

- photonovel (static on a page or as slideshow-movie)
- comic
- animation (stop motion, Flash etc.)
- radio show (War of the Worlds)
- computer game (text adventure, etc.)
- advertising
- music video
- tv interview
- illustrated newspaper article
- story with illustrations
- dance to spoken text
- animate lego blocks or other toys and narrate a story with it
- opera (sing and act a story)
- make a silent (!) movie and play live music to it
- film someone writing a story in sand (at the beach or wipe when you reach the edge of the sand box)
- write a story in morse code with tansliteration
- film someone writing a story with a finger on a person's back and that person speaking it
- write a user's manual as a poem

Just combine any one or two media into something new! Endless possibilities. Interesting results :-)

Comment: Yes that would be an accurate representation. Multimedia for a story or a poem :) Ah yes comic books, stories and advertising have all been given by the tutors before me. The department wants something new every year.

Comment: That is a more than ample list. Thank you :)